# WaveDrom Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer, javascript, waveform

How can I get [WaveDrom](http://code.google.com/p/wavedrom/) to work in IE8? Is there a quick way to do this by including something like [js7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/). If not, how difficult would it be to manually add this functionality myself into the library? Thanks!

Is it possible to get something like [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) to get it to work?

Has anyone gotten it to work in IE with the Google Chrome Frame?

Comment: Have you tried it in IE9, IE10 or IE11? According to the page you linked, this software doesn't support IE at all... *any version.* That may or may not be accurate (I haven't tried it), but it certainly isn't encouraging for you. If it is possible then I would guess that [svgweb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) would be more appropriate than Raphael, and you'll likely need Modernizr as well, and probably other polyfills. But I have my doubts that you're going to get anywhere. My guess is that the simple answer to your question is "No, it's not possible."

Comment: The project moved to GitHub: [wavedrom.github.io](http://wavedrom.github.io) It should work with IE11. Let me know if it doesn't.